# What is the Question Asking?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a function on $[0, \infty)$ such that for each point in its graph, $(x,y) = (y^2,y)$. At how many points must each such f have a limit?
>
> (A) 1
>
> (B) 2
>
> (C) 3
>
> (D) 4
>
> (E) Infinitely many

I am having trouble parsing these two sentences. If $(x,y)$ is a point on the graph, then $y=f(x)$ and the condition becomes $(x,f(x)) = (f(x)^2,f(x)$, which is what I believe the first sentence is saying. As for the second, I haven't the foggiest notion. I believe $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is an example of a function satisfying the condition alluded to in the first sentence, since $f(f(x)^2) = \sqrt{f(x)^2} = f(x)$, in which case we have a function with a limit at infinitely many points (yes? no?). I don't know if this is necessary, however, which is what the problem is asking for (that much I do know!). By the way, the answer is (A), if that helps in interpreting the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that with a point where $f$ has a limit, they mean a point $a\in[0,\infty)$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists.

We certainly have $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0$ because $f(x)^2\to 0$ implies $f(x)\to 0$.
So that's one such point.
There *need not* exist any other as can be seen from considering 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt x&x\in\Bbb Q\\-\sqrt x&x\notin \Bbb Q\end{cases} $$

Comment: So the function I gave does not satisfy the condition? If it does satisfy the condition, then I think this is an ill-posed question, since the word 'must' connotes necessity, and the answer being (A) means that the condition necessarily implies that all such functions have 1 point at which they have a limit. But if my function satisfies the condition, then this implication is not necessarily true.